# Big picture book from the late 70s or early 80s about a boy and a goblin

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

I read this in the very early 80s and it was a fairly new book then. It was one of the tall books for kids that was so popular then.

It was about a boy who moved onto a farm out in the country. His family might have had to move in with his grandparents but I am not sure on this. The boy was told that there was a goblin who lived in the woods on or very near the farm and to never go in them. Of course he did and found the goblin who was angry at his space being invaded. The boy ran out of the woods and went home. Later that night the boy was lying in bed in fear when he looked out the window and saw the goblin looking for him or coming for him in a cornfield very close to the house.